# How to draw parabolic graph and its tangent

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wanted to draw a parabolic graph of y=x^2 and draw the tangents and angle between tangent and graph as shown in picture using pgfplots, can any one help me out.

[image: This type of graph]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please, consider add an example of what do you want and what problems did you come across.

Comment: A parabola has infinitely many tangent lines.  Are there specific points at which you wish to draw the tangents?

Comment: In future may be helpful the answer on this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579785/runaway-argument-in-beamer-slide (don't be confused by title, there given explanation about tangents is very educative). It is in Spanish, but it can be (by used math) easy to understand. You may also translate text to your native language. I'm confident, that aforementioned link is more helpful as one given as notice for closing of your question.

Answer (score 5):

With `tkz-fct / TikZ`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] \tkzInit[xmax=2,ymax=4] 
\tkzGrid  \tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[color = red,thick, domain =0:2]{x*x}
\tkzDrawTangentLine[draw, kl = 0.8, kr = 0.8](0) 
\tkzDrawTangentLine[draw, kl = 0.8,kr = 0.8 ](1) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=red]{x^2};
\addplot[color=blue]{0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this (wiith TikZ):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,scale=1.5]
        \draw [gray!10,line width=.3pt] (-3,-1) grid (3,5);     
        \draw [->,style=thick] (-3.2,0) -- (3.3,0) node[pos=1,right] {$x$}; 
        \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} \draw[thick] (\x,-0.05) to (\x,0.05) node[black,below] at (\x,-0.05) {$\x$}; 
        \draw [->,style=thick] (0,-1.20) -- (0,5) node[pos=1,right] {$y$}; 
        \foreach \x in {-1,...,5} \draw[thick] (-0.05,\x) to (0.05,\x) node[black,left] at (-0.05,\x) {$\x$};
        \draw [cyan, domain=-2.2:2.2, samples=50] plot (\x, {\x*\x }); %parabola
        \draw [magenta, domain=0:3, samples=50] plot (\x, {2*\x- 1}); % tangent in x=1
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Please can you tell me how to draw angle in between line of graph and slope as like I have updated.